# Spring Web Flow flowExecutionUrl is empty

Tags: spring, spring-webflow

I'm making simple order-flow via Spring Web Flow, also i have Spring MVC on my project. I've been doing everything according to guides, but my web-app doesn't react to my flow at all. Spring Web Flow Config:

```
     @Configuration
     @ComponentScan(basePackages = "config")
     public class WebFlowConfig extends AbstractFlowConfiguration {
@Bean
public FlowBuilderServices flowBuilderServices() {
    return getFlowBuilderServicesBuilder()
            .setViewFactoryCreator(mvcViewFactoryCreator())
            .setDevelopmentMode(true).build();
}

@Bean
public MvcViewFactoryCreator mvcViewFactoryCreator() {
    MvcViewFactoryCreator factoryCreator = new MvcViewFactoryCreator();
    factoryCreator.setViewResolvers(

    Collections.singletonList(this.webMvcConfig.resourceViewResolver()));
    factoryCreator.setUseSpringBeanBinding(true);
    return factoryCreator;
}
@Autowired
private DispatcherConfig webMvcConfig;

@Bean
public FlowDefinitionRegistry flowRegistry() {
   FlowDefinitionRegistry registry = getFlowDefinitionRegistryBuilder().addFlowLocation("/WEB-INF/flows/order/flowcnf.xml","order").build();
   return registry;
}

@Bean
public FlowExecutor flowExecutor() {
    return

            getFlowExecutorBuilder(flowRegistry()).build();
}

@Bean
public FlowHandlerMapping flowHandlerMapping(){
    final FlowHandlerMapping handeler = new FlowHandlerMapping();
    handeler.setFlowRegistry(flowRegistry());
    handeler.setFlowUrlHandler(defaultFlowUrlHandler());
    return handeler;
}
@Bean
public DefaultFlowUrlHandler defaultFlowUrlHandler(){
    return new DefaultFlowUrlHandler();
}

@Bean
public FlowHandlerAdapter adapter(){
    FlowHandlerAdapter adapter = new FlowHandlerAdapter();
    adapter.setFlowUrlHandler(defaultFlowUrlHandler());
    adapter.setFlowExecutor(flowExecutor());
    return adapter;
}
}
```

As I said I'm using Spring MVC maybe the problems occurs due to it.

Code snippet below must run "thankCustomer" view-state, but it doesn't.
I get 404 eror if i click the link.

```
<a class=button href="${flowExecutionUrl}&_eventId=thankCustomer">Замовити!</a>
```

And the flow code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd"
  start-state="identify">
<var name="order" class="entity.BookOrder"/> 

<subflow-state id="identify" subflow="order/custom" >
    <output name="user" value="order.custName" />
    <transition on="userIsReady" to="buildOrder"/>
</subflow-state>

<subflow-state id="buildOrder" subflow="order/build">
    <input name="order" value="order" />
    <transition to="takePayment" on="orderBuilt" />
</subflow-state>


<subflow-state id="takePayment" subflow="order/takePayment" >
    <input name="order" value="order"/>
    <transition on="paymentTaken" to="saveOrder" />
</subflow-state>
<action-state id="saveOrder">
    <evaluate expression="userServiceImpl.addOrder(order.custName,order)"/>
    <transition to="thankCustomer" />
</action-state>

<view-state id="thankCustomer" view="/WEB-INF/pages/greeting.jsp" >
    <transition to="end-point" />
</view-state>

<end-state id="end-point"/>

<global-transitions>
    <transition on="cancel" to="end-point" />
</global-transitions>

</flow>
```

I've tried to put flow id (order) instead of empty flowExecutionUrl, but still the same eror, I'll be grateful for any kinda help.

Comment: there are no transitions on event `thankCustomer` in your flow.

Comment: saveOrder action-state ? Anyway I'm connecting directly to the view-state using  `href="${flowExecutionUrl}&_eventId=thankCustomer"`, aren't I ?

Comment: the xml file is your flow. in this case it looks like it is `order`. so first, you enter your order flow (/order) then you can transition with an event. in this case your event is `thankCustomer` but there is no such transition in your order flow. you cannot enter part of your flow directly, at least not like that

Comment: I replaced  `start-state="identify"` with `start-state="saveOrder"` but nothing has changed, when I go to localhost:8080/order/ i still getting 404 eror (Page Not Found)

Comment: where is your xml file located? can you confirm it's in `/WEB-INF/flows/order/flowcnf.xml`. also, can you paste the stack trace of the 404 error

Comment: Thank you for your help! The problem was that i didn't set order to my FlowHandlerMapping in WebFlowConfig !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to set "order" to my FlowHandlerMapping Bean, couse i already had 2 viewResolvers.